# Only copy cells if a value doesn't exist in a range - VBA If Statement

Tags: vba, if-statement

I want to use an If statement where if the value of a cell doesn't exist in a range then the If statement is true and the action of copying cells into a different worksheet is carried out. The section of code i'm having trouble with is -

```
If (Value < Date And CompletedValue = "") And (Cells(Examrow, 1).Value <> SummarySheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(100, 1)).Value) Then
```

The code worked fine without the `And Cells(Examrow, 1).Value <> SummarySheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(100, 1)).Value) Then` section so i figure this is where i'm going wrong.

It should look at the cell (Examrow, 1), get the value and then compare it to all of the cells in range A3:A:100 in the worksheet SummarySheet. If the value is not already in the range specified, then the if statement should do its thing.

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

The error message i get is:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3yeA.png)

Comment: It is always helpful to know the error message... You did a good job narrowing down the problem though :)

Comment: I'll update it with the error message :)

Comment: Oh that message changes it. Is your active worksheet something other than `SummarySheet`?

Comment: Yeah, the active sheet is the one which the Cell(Examrow, 1) comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** after you added the error message:

The `someWorksheet.Range` method takes two arguments in the form of ranges. These ranges have to be on the worksheet `someWorksheet`. If you use `Cells(3, 1)`, you don't tell VBA on which sheet the cell is so it guesses that you mean the `ActiveSheet`. If `ActiveSheet` is not `someWorksheet` you will get the error because the `Range` method of `someWorksheet` cannot deal with ranges from another worksheet. The answer is obviously to specify the sheet of `Cells(3, 1)` and `Cells(100, 1)`:

```
SummarySheet.Range(SummarySheet.Cells(3, 1), SummarySheet.Cells(100, 1))
```

If you are hardcoding it anyway, you could also just use

```
SummarySheet.Range("A3:A100")
```

This obviously also goes for your other cell references.

---

However you will receive a new error after that because you cannot compare a single value to an array. You either have to loop through all the cells of the range or use the built-in `.Find` method:

```
someRange.Find(someValue)
```

will return the cell where `someValue` is first found or `Nothing`, if it is not found. So you just need to check if the above `Is Nothing`:

```
If SummarySheet.Range("A3:A100").Find(Cells(Examrow, 1).Value) Is Nothing Then
```

You should set the other [options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) to suit your needs because they could be saved from a previous search.

This could look something like this:

```
Dim foundCell As Range 'to keep the If condition readable

Set foundCell = SummarySheet.Range("A3:A100").Find( _
    What:=yourValue, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    MatchCase:=True)

If (.....) And foundCell Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thank you very much, It's not working perfectly but i think that will be a separate problem! Thanks again

Comment: I think i've found the issue i was having and it may be related to this. I have 3 cells that have the word "Hot" in it.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Sorry, didnt mean to press enter i'll start again. I think i've found the issue i was having and it may be related to this. I have 3 cells that have the word "Hot" in it; "Hot hands", "Hot", and "Hot feet" and Its not picking up the "Hot" cell. Is this because the .Find method returns "someValue" for the hot cell since its in the other 2 so skips the If function?

Comment: That's what the `LookAt` argument is for. Have you set it to `xlWhole`?

Comment: I originally ran it using If ' SummarySheet.Range("A3:A100").Find(Cells(Examrow, 1).Value) Is Nothing Then ' method. When i try the other method, depending on where i put it, either nothing happens or i get an error "duplicate deceleration in current scope"

Comment: Ok, played with it and got it sorted, it was the LookAt argument, thank you again!